# Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp causes stackoverflow error?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

If I'm correct, I should *definitely* not be getting a stackoverflow error while using Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp, especially only directly after starting my program.

Here's my code:

```
if (currentTicks >= lastTicks + interval)
        {
            lastTicks = currentTicks;
            return true;
        }
```

currentTicks being placed in by Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp(). This bit of code is in a method called infinitely (I'm using it to control FPS). Anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:
Main form code:

```
    Game game;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        game = new Game(Stopwatch.Frequency / 45);
        MainLoop();
    }

    public void MainLoop()
    {
        if (game.DrawStuff(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()))
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        MainLoop();
    }`
```

Then, the Game class:

```
    public long lastTicks { get; set; }

    public double interval { get; set; }

    public Game(double Interval)
    {
        interval = Interval;
    }

    public bool DrawStuff(long currentTicks)
    {
        if (currentTicks >= lastTicks + interval)
        {
            lastTicks = currentTicks;
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It stops on "if (currentTicks >= lastTicks + interval)". I can see the value of currentTicks is 30025317628568. Everything else cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Where is that code declared? Can you show more of the code surrounding it? Also, how is `currentTicks`, `lastTicks` and `interval` declared?

Comment: Impossible to answer from the snippet you provided. The only thing I can ensure you is the GetTimeStamp is definitely not the one causing this exception.

Comment: What if he's nearly exhausted the stack when he calls GetTimeStamp? It wouldn't be GetTimeStamp's fault, but it would look like it.

Comment: When running under the *debugger*, you will still get the stack overflow -- but the call stack pane will show you the full stack.  This will tell you with crystal clarity what the culprit is.

Comment: +1 for exhausted the stack at the call.

Comment: What are curretTicks, lastTicks and interval? Fields? Variables? Properties?

Comment: @Skurmedel - possible, but *exceptionally* unlikely IMO

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.  This obviously doesn't.

Comment: Go easy on the closing, he could at least get some time to edit his answer.

Comment: Hope the edits help. Really scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but this is a horrible way to control FPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling MainLoop recursively (aka [infinite recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_recursion#Infinite_recursion)), which means that you're overflowing the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). GetTimeStamp is a red herring here.

Remove the call to MainLoop from within itself and just use a standard while loop :

```
while (game.DrawStuff(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()))
{
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @BloodyAugust: ... and that's why it's always important to post all your source code ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the posted code is part of the getter of a property callled `currentTicks`, `lastTicks` or even `interval`.

And so the question turns out to be about using proper Caps for properties.

Comment: As you can see (now), it is not.